# Trouble with Havel-Hakimi algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib, networkx, graph-theory

I am currently developing a custom algorithm for class that implements the Havel-Hakimi algorithm choosing a node randomly. Unfortunately I have run into a logical error that is hard for me to trace (since I am a beginner in programming).I would appreciate it if someone could help me spot the issue. What happens is I get the correct sequence returned sometimes, but other times not

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def nodes_connected(G,u,v):
    return u in G.neighbors(v)

def hh_graph(seq):
    if not(nx.is_graphical(seq)):
        print("Sequence is not graphical")
    else:
        #Randomly mix the degree sequence
        random.shuffle(seq)
        #Create graph
        G = nx.Graph()
        G.add_nodes_from(range(1,len(seq)+1))
        #Repeat for every node in the sequence
        for i in range(0,len(seq)):
            #j stores number of edges to be added
            j=seq[i]
            #selected node is zeroed
            seq[i]=0
            #Repeat till all edges have been connected
            while j>0:
                k=0
                done=False
                #Repeat till finding a suitable node to connect to
                while k<len(seq) and done==False :
                    #Check to connect to a maximum value node,and avoiding a duplicate connection
                    if seq[k]==max(seq) and nodes_connected(G,i+1,k+1)==False:
                        G.add_edges_from([[i+1,k+1]])
                        seq[k]-=1
                        done=True
                    k+=1
                j-=1
        #Check graph degree sequence to validate results
        degree_sequence = [d for n, d in G.degree()]
        print(f"Graph degree sequence {degree_sequence}")
        #nx.draw_networkx(G)
        #plt.show()

A=[5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
B=[6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,1,1]
C=[4,3,2,1]
hh_graph(A)
hh_graph(B)
hh_graph(C)
```

I have tried to focus on the loops where I think there might be an issue.I have tested different if cases and implementations,but still cant understand how it works half of the time and other times not

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Havel-Hakimi algorithm requires that you add edges for the (current) highest degree node to the subsequent highest degree nodes at each step. To do that, you would need to re-sort the list (at least partially) after each node is added & edges populated. You don't choose a random node (degree value) to populate with edges.

My understanding from your comment is that this is deliberate - you are evaluating a variation on Havel-Hakimi where a random degree node is attached the to appropriate maximum-remaining degree nodes. However if there is a step of more than one in the degree values of the appropriate nodes, they will never pass the `seq[k]==max(seq)` test. In your comment example of `6,3,3,3,2,2,1,1`, selecting a `3` node in the first step would find `6` but never find the other `3`s.

You would probably be better off not to implicitly use the degree list position as the node ID as you currently do; instead make each entry `[remainingdegree,nodeID]` so that you can sort freely on remaining degree values. Then you could still select randomly from the sorted list for which node to exhaust next, but you would know where to look for the nodes to connect it to.

Then you could run the main loop like this (& you could add the "graphical" test within this):

```py
            G.add_nodes_from(range(1,len(seq)+1))
            # make list of [degree,ID] lists (& sort descending)
            nodeRecs = sorted(([d,i+1] for i,d in enumerate(seq)), reverse=True)
            # Add edges to random node choices until highest degree is zero
            while nodeRecs[0][0] > 0:
                # remove exhausted nodes
                while (nodeRecs[-1][0] == 0):
                    nodeRecs.pop()
                # choose new active node
                addRec = random.choice(nodeRecs)
                # link to high-degree nodes
                for toRec in nodeRecs:
                    if toRec[1] != addRec[1]:
                        G.add_edges_from([[addRec[1],toRec[1]]])
                        toRec[0] -= 1
                        addRec[0] -= 1
                        if addRec[0] == 0: 
                            break
                # Put nodes back into descending degree order
                nodeRecs.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: actually,this is half true.This is the reason the professor asked us to implement this code.While its true that each given node must be connected to the other highest-degree nodes available,you do not have to select the highest degree node each time to populate with edges

Comment: for eg in 6,3,3,3,2,2,1,1 you can select a 3 and connect it to 6,another 3,another 3

Comment: heh, I think your professor ought to add their name on then, because that's not Havel-Hakimi but some sketchy variation on it. I shall consider your variant.

Comment: @NewCookie There might be a couple of Python constructs/conventions you aren't familiar with here; let me know if you need an explanation. `enumerate` and `sorted` are [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

By the Havel-Hakimi theorem from https://d3gt.com/unit.html?havel-hakimi, we have the following:

[image]

from which we have the following algorithm:

Iteratively execute the following steps

- Sort the degree sequence list in non-increasing order.
- Extract (remove) the max-degree vertex of degree d from the sorted degree-sequence list.
- Decrement the degrees of next d vertices in the list
- If there are not enough vertices in the list, or degree of some vertex becomes negative, return False
- Stop and return True if list of all zeros remains.

Here is how you can implement the above Havel-Hakimi algorithm to draw a simple graph, given its degree sequence, provided such a graph exists:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

def get_adj_list(deg_seq):        
    deg_seq = np.array(deg_seq)
    labels = np.arange(len(deg_seq))
    adj_list = {}
    while True:
        indices = np.argsort(-deg_seq)
        deg_seq = deg_seq[indices]
        labels = labels[indices]
        if all(deg_seq == 0):
            return adj_list     
        v = deg_seq[0]            
        if v > len(deg_seq[1:]):
            return None             
        for i in range(1,v+1):
            deg_seq[i] -= 1
            if deg_seq[i] < 0:
                return None
            adj_list[labels[0]] = adj_list.get(labels[0], []) + [labels[i]]            
        deg_seq[0] = 0            
    return None     
 
deg_seqs = [[5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
            [6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,1,1],
            [4,3,2,1],
            [3, 3, 3, 3]]

for deg_seq in deg_seqs:
    adj_list = get_adj_list(deg_seq)
    if adj_list:
        print('The graph with {} can be drawn'.format(deg_seq))
        #print(adj_list)
        G = nx.from_dict_of_lists(adj_list)#.to_undirected()
        nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G), with_labels=True)
        plt.show()
    else:
        print('The graph with {} can\'t be drawn'.format(deg_seq))
```

The following animations show how the graphs are drawn with the algorithm, given the corresponding degree-sequence lists.

[image]

Graph with degree sequence [5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]:
[image]

Graph with degree sequence [6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,1,1]:
[image]

Graph with degree sequence [3, 3, 3, 3]:
[image]